# What system libraries are required to support Pillow on Raspbian Buster Lite?

Tags: python-3, raspbian-buster

After installing Pillow, I get errors such as:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 90, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: libopenjp2.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I could, one by one, find all these additional libraries required and install them individually, but it would much more convenient to have a canonical list or a single package that took care of them.

I though the `python-pil` system package would install all these, and it does, as well as Pillow itself, but Pillow installed via Pip - for example in a virtualenv, which I need - will not find the libraries that `python3-pil` includes.

Is there a more convenient way of installing these libraries?

Comment: Does https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#external-libraries help?

Comment: It sounds like you have installed software without using the package system (package system modules are tested for compatability).

Comment: The Pillow docs are useful and give some examples in the `/depends` section of the repository for system-level dependencies that will be required on various systems, but the closest match was (I think) Debian 8.

Comment: I think it's critical to reframe this question as being *inside a virtual environment*. Otherwise, `sudo apt install python3-pil` will do the needful for most users.

Comment: @scruss I don't think it is the virtual environment that makes the difference, but the installation of Pillow with Pip. However I would need to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for.

In short, it's:

```
sudo apt install libwebp6 libtiff5 libjbig0 liblcms2-2 libwebpmux3 libopenjp2-7 libzstd1 libwebpdemux2
```

I found the list at https://www.piwheels.org/project/Pillow/.

Once I have those installed, Pillow seems to work as expected in my virtual environment.

Answer (score 3):

Did you install `python3-pil`? `python-pil` is for Python 2, which you aren't running.

It looks like the problem is more you're trying to open a JPEG-2000 image (… `ImportError: libopenjp2.so.7: cannot open shared object file` …). For reasons of mostly-obsolete dogma, JP2 support on Linux has been weak for many years. You may find that installing libopenjp2 fixes the problem:

```
sudo apt install libopenjp2-7 libopenjp2-7-dev libopenjp2-tools
```

Comment: [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#external-libraries) suggest Pillow uses `openjpeg`, but your system was explicitly looking for libopenjp2

Comment: Well-spotted regarding `python3-pil`, I missed that. However, having installed it, I still have the same result. I'm not trying yet to open any particular image - just `from PIL import Image`, in the example above, which appears to demand `libopenjp2.so.7`. From experience, once that's fixed, the next complaint will be about a TIFF library, and so on.